# PCRE whole word match (only spaces allowed as separator)

Tags: php, preg-match, pcre

I want to match string as a whole word match `"~\b$search\b~i"`, it matches '35' to '35-40'. I want only space to be separator between words.

Test cases:
Matching 35 in following cases:

- 35-40 => false
- 3-5 => false
- 335 => false
- 350 => false
- 35 => true

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of word boundary assertions:

```
~(?<!\S)$search(?!\S)~i
```

Here `(?<!\S)` asserts that there is no non-whitespace character (`\S`) preceding and `(?!\S)` asserts that there is no non-whitespace character following `$search`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for amazing and fast answer!